# Generalizing Adamek's categories of $T$-spaces

Tags: category-theory

This post is meant to get some possible reference on a topic that I do not see very much in literature.

Well, in "The Joy of Cats" the category of $T$-spaces is introduced. Given a covariant functor $T$ from a category $\mathfrak{C}$ to the category of sets, the authors say that a $T$-space is a pair $(X,K)$ where $X$ is an object of $\mathfrak{C}$ and $K \subseteq T(X)$. Regarding the morphisms, a function $f: X \to Y$ goes to a function $T(f): T(X) \to T(Y)$ in such a way to send elements of $K$ to elements of $K'$. This choice implies the covariance of the functor $T$, but nothing prevents to use a contravariant functor in the above definition, and to change suitably the notations (see http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/17/tr17.pdf, Def. 5.40, page 73).

Now, it seems obvious to generalize the perspective. Let $\mathfrak{D}$ be a category and $T: \mathfrak{C} \to \mathfrak{D}$ a covariant functor. Then I call a $T$-space a pair $(X,K)$ where $X$ is an object of $\mathfrak{C}$ and $K$ is a subobject of $T(X)$ in the category $\mathfrak{D}$. Is there a natural choice for morphisms in such a case? If yes, have these categories been already studied elsewhere? Finally, what happens when choosing contravariant functors, namely is it possible to define in a natural way morphisms in this case?

Comment: The obvious translation from the Set-based situation is: A morphism from $(X,K)$ to $(X',K')$ is a map $f\colon X\to X'$ such that $f\circ \iota_K\colon K\to X'$ factors through $\iota_{K'} \colon K'\to X'$ (this is independent of the particular representative mono for the subobject). Similar for the contravariant case. In fact in both cases there are two versions, depending on two possible choices for the inclusion of subobjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rephrasing Def. 5.40, pg. 73:
Let $\boldsymbol{X}$ and $\boldsymbol{Set}$ be categories (the latter is the usual suspect). Then take
$$T:\boldsymbol{X}\to \boldsymbol{Set}$$
to be a [covariant] functor. Then the **category of $T$-spaces** is just:
$$\color{red}{\boldsymbol{Spa(T)}} := \Bigg\{\bigg\{\color{red}{(X,\alpha)}\text{ }\bigg|\text{ }\alpha\subseteq T(X)\bigg\},\text{ }\text{ }\bigg\{\color{red}{(X,\alpha)\to (Y,\beta)}\text{ }\bigg|\text{ }\big(T(X)\to T(Y)\big)(\alpha)\subseteq \beta\bigg\}\Bigg\}$$
$$= \bigg\{Obj(\boldsymbol{Spa(T)}),\text{ } Mor(\boldsymbol{Spa(T)})\bigg\},$$
where of course $X,Y\in \boldsymbol{X}$ are free.

---

---

By the defining condition for the **T-maps** (i.e. morphisms in $\boldsymbol{Spa(T)}$), it should be clear that $T$ must be covariant, since otherwise $T(f)$ would have reversed domain and codomain and hence wouldn't be able to accept $\alpha\subseteq T(X)$. One could swap $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in the condition to force contra-variant to work.
Replace $\alpha \leftrightarrow K$, $\beta \leftrightarrow K'$, and $\boldsymbol{\mathfrak{C}}\leftrightarrow \boldsymbol{X}$ to get your notation.
To generalize, let's repeat the one liner with red texts with appropriate changes:

---

For covariant functor $T:\boldsymbol{X}\to\boldsymbol{Y}$, define:
$\color{red}{\widetilde{\boldsymbol{Spa(T)}}} := \Bigg\{\bigg\{\color{red}{(X,\alpha)}\text{ }\bigg|\text{ }\alpha:=[Y\hookrightarrow T(X)]_{\sim}\bigg\},$
$$\bigg\{\color{red}{(X_1,\alpha_1)\to (X_2,\alpha_2)}\text{ }\bigg|\text{ }\exists \iota_{\alpha_1\alpha_2}:\big[\big(T(X_1)\to T(X_2)\big)\circ \iota_{\alpha_1}(Y_1)\hookrightarrow T(X_2)\big]_{\sim}\hookrightarrow \alpha_2\bigg\}\Bigg\},$$
where we have *equivalence classes of monomorphisms* $[\cdot \hookrightarrow \cdot\cdot]_{\sim}$ defining a subobject of $\cdot \cdot$. In the second definition we need to define a *subobject of a subobject*, but $T(f)$ doesn't operate on subobjects and may need to be monic itself for the composition to be monic. This may impose another restriction. At this point, a picture helps:
$\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }$[image]

It remains to show this definition is independent of representative, $\iota_{\alpha_1}:Y_1\hookrightarrow T(X_1)$, but this can be done. Existence of such an $\iota_{\alpha_1'\alpha_2}$ implies existence of $\iota_{\alpha_1\alpha_2}$ [Exercise].

---

*This concludes my attempt at generalization. I have not seen this considered in any other texts (also have not seen $T$-spaces considered either). The closest thing I've seen are representations of functors with universal elements etc., but these are elements $u\in T(X)$ not subsets, so there is a distinction.*

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful reply. Concerning the contravariant case, just swapping $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ as in the case ${\bf Set}$ should work, right?

Comment: For the contravariant functor case, we are looking at $T(X_2)\to T(X_1)$ (reverse the middle arrow in the picture). We would then have as input $\iota_{\alpha_2}(Y_2)$, provided then the composition is monic, it would be into $T(X_1)$ and finally the created subobject would have to be a sub-object of $\alpha_1$. So long story short, permute indices 1 and 2.